# Avoiding spurious construction and destruction in RAII timer object

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, factory

I have a `Timer` object which should time the region of code from its construction to its destruction. These `Timer` objects are created by and associated with a long-lived `TimerManager` object. In fact, the `Timer` objects are just thin wrappers around a pointer to `TimerManager` which does the heavy lifting.

I'd like the user the `Timer` objects like this:

```cpp
TimerManager manager; // maybe a global, thread local, whatever

...
{
  Timer timer = manager.newTimer();
  // code under test

} // timer object destroyed and timer stops here
```

The `Timer` object can be as simple as:

```cpp
class Timer {
  TimerManager* manager_;
public:
  Timer(TimerManager* manager) : manager_(manager) {
    manager_->start();
  }

  ~Timer() {
    manager_->stop();
  }
};
```

Here all the heavy lifting of starting and stopping the timer is delegated to the manager.

However, if I implement `TimerManager::newTimer()` like so:

```cpp
TimerManager::newTimer() {
  Timer t(this);
  // ...
  return t;
}
```

Then depending on whether RVO kicks in, I may get a spurious construction and destruction of `Timer` object `t`, different from the real region I want to time in the calling code.

I could instead use the following code to initialize Timer objects:

```
{
  Timer timer(&manager);
  // code under test

} // timer object destroyed and timer stops here
```

This ensures extra `Timer` objects are not created or destroyed, but I prefer the assignment syntax, especially since it lets me have various `newTimer()` type methods with different behavior. Is there any way to get something like this w/o having the extra side effects of `Timer` creation and destruction.

Performance matters here.

I am not using C++17 so I cannot avail myself of guaranteed return value optimization.

Comment: Well, even though you prefer the assignment syntax you cannot use it because you do not have guaranteed RVO pre C++17. Either update to C++17, or use the alternative syntax. This is pretty much cut and dry. I see no workaround, here, except perhaps have `newTimer()` return a `std::shared_ptr`. But, since you claim that "performance matters", this translates to two extra heap allocations, one for the `Timer`, and one for the reference counter that `std::shared_ptr` independently allocates. Those are, pretty much, your only choices. Pick one.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik - I see some alternatives: e.g., the `newTimer()` method could return some type of proxy object rather than a `Timer` directly, which could wrap the same pointer, but without the construction/destruction semantics. Or maybe the `Timer` object could use a reference count to detect the "last" destruction. Those don't seem all that great, but it makes me think that it is not all that cut and dry and that better may exist.

Comment: Give `Timer` a move constructor and move assignment operator. Don't call `start` there. Reset `manager_` to `nullptr` in moved-from object, so its destructor doesn't call `stop`. Basically, `Timer` will be similar to `unique_ptr`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: Basically `Timer` should be based on `std::unique_ptr<TimerManager, TimerStopper>` (containment or private inheritance) and then all the right special member functions immediately work and the right ones are implicitly deleted.

Answer (score 3):

You need to make the manager noncopyable and provide the appropriate move operations.  The move operations should transfer the resource and set the moved-from manager to `nullptr`.  The destructor should be able to handle the `nullptr` case.  As in:

```
class Timer {
  TimerManager* manager_;
public:
  Timer(TimerManager* manager) : manager_(manager) {
    manager_->start();
  }

  Timer(const Timer&) = delete; // noncopyable

  Timer(Timer&& timer)          // move constructor
    :manager_{nullptr}
  {
    swap(*this, timer);
  }

  Timer& operator=(Timer timer) // (move-only) assignment operator
  {
    swap(*this, timer);
    return *this;
  }

  friend void swap(Timer& lhs, Timer& rhs)
  {
    swap(lhs.manager_, rhs.manager_);
  }

  ~Timer() {                    // take care of nullptr
    if (manager_)
      manager_->stop();
  }
};
```

I used the [copy-and-swap](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3279543) idiom here.  This way, if the `Timer` is returned, as in

```
TimerManager::newTimer() {
  Timer t(this);
  // ...
  return t;
}
```

Then `t` is moved instead of copied.  Only pointers are passed and the timer is not interrupted.  And the timer is only started and stopped once.

Also, the whole thing is unnecessary if you make effective use of the library, i.e., `unique_ptr` with a custom deleter:

```
struct Stopper {
    void operator()(TimerManager* tm)
    {
        tm->stop();
    }
};

class Timer {
    std::unique_ptr<TimerManager, Stopper> manager_;
public:
    Timer(TimerManager* manager)
        :manager_{manager}
    {
        manager_->start();
    }

    // everything is automatically correct
};
```

Comment: @BenVoigt My theory is that the assignment operator can only be called with an rvalue, so there is no copy after all.  What am I missing?

Comment: @BenVoigt Well, is swapping with the rvalue directly good practice I wonder?  My first impression is that the assignment operator should terminate the current timer, but I may be wrong.

Comment: @BenVoigt But that way we have to duplicate the destructor code.

Comment: @BenVoigt If you don't stop the timer in the move assignment, the pointer to the timer is lost.  How to stop it then?

Comment: @BenVoigt The self-assignment check may still be omitted with `manager_ = exchange(other.manager_, nullptr)`, though, so I don't consider it an advantage of the current version

Comment: Oh you mean the one formerly owned by lhs...  I had overlooked that.  Initially I was thinking of a call to `reset()` (which would have run the cleanup on the existing value) but then I saw that the pointer was raw.  Really the whole thing could be done with `std::unique_ptr<TimerManager, TimerStopper>` for the type of the member pointer, and then the Rule of Zero applies and you don't need to write move constructor, assignment, or swap yourself, and write `TimerStopper` instead of a destructor.

Comment: @BenVoigt Agree on `unique_ptr`.  I'm updating my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197107/discussion-between-l-f-and-ben-voigt).

Answer (score 0):

If you can reorganize your function to:

```
Timer TimerManager::newTimer() {
   // ...
   t(this);
   return t; // Depend of NRVO :(
}
```

then you might use copy-list-initialization which construct returned object in place:

```
Timer TimerManager::newTimer() {
   // ...
   return {this}; // construct returned object in place, as NRVO :-)
}
```

But you still have possible move with:

```
Timer timer = manager.newTimer();
```

You might change it to:

```
const Timer& timer = manager.newTimer();
```

or

```
Timer&& timer = manager.newTimer();
```

deleting copy and move constructor makes that construct viable.

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/11d0e4b2f39b8c16)